# gets() is repeating the lines before it in C

Tags: c

I'm doing an assignment for college, and when my loop calls `gets()`, it prints the lines I wanted printed twice. This only happens on the second loop. If you type triangle on the first loop and enter some numbers, then after the loop finished and restarts, it will print the prompt sequence twice, instead of once.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main() {
    const float pi = 3.1415926535;  // Constant for pi
    char choice[100] = "";          // String for inputted, also used for exiting loop
    float height, width, base, area, radius, radians, verticalHeight;
    int i = 1;

    while (i < 2) {
        puts("Area Calculator - Please choose one of the choices listed below\n----------------------------------------------------\nTriangle, Rectangle, Circle, Trapezium\n----------------------------------------------------");
        printf("Enter choice: ");
        gets(choice);
        
        if (strcmp(choice, "Done") == 0 || (strcmp(choice, "done") == 0)) {
            i++;
        }
        else if (strcmp(choice, "Triangle") == 0 || (strcmp(choice, "triangle") == 0)) {
            printf("\nEnter vertical height: ");
            scanf_s("%f", &verticalHeight);
            printf("Enter base: ");
            scanf_s("%f", &base);
            printf("Area = %.2f\n\n", (0.5) * verticalHeight * base);
            strcpy_s(choice, 100, "");
        }
        else if (strcmp(choice, "Rectangle") == 0 || (strcmp(choice, "rectangle") == 0)) {
            puts("\nrectangle");
        }
        else if (strcmp(choice, "Circle") == 0 || (strcmp(choice, "circle") == 0)) {
            puts("\ncircle");
        }
        else if (strcmp(choice, "Trapezium") == 0 || (strcmp(choice, "trapezium") == 0)) {
            puts("\ntrapezium");
        } 
    }
}
```

I tried using `scanf_s()` instead of `gets()` and I can get it to work like that, however my assignment specifies that I have to use `gets()`.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: 1) don't use `gets()`, it's been removed from the C language in 2011. 2) don't use `scanf()` for user input, it wasn't designed for that. Use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: [Don't use `gets`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used). And don't mix input methods (like `gets` + `scanf`). Mixing output methods isn't the best idea as well.

Comment: "however my assignment specifies that I have to use gets()": your instructor needs a stern talking-to.  Unless the next assignment is going to be to write an exploit for this one.

Comment: `scanf_s` was added in C11 and `gets` was removed in C11. Chances are that you also have `gets_s` that also was added in C11.

Comment: The `scanf_s` (or `scanf`) calls will leave the newline character at the end of the input line unread, so the next `gets` (or `fgets`) call will read an empty line. You can fix it by using `scanf_s` (or `scanf`) to read the `choice` string instead of using `gets` (or `fgets`).

Comment: If you must use `gets` to read `choice`, you could put a call to `scanf(" ");` before the call to `gets` to discard any initial whitespace, including the newline character left unread by the previous call to `scanf_s`.

Comment: Also, if you must use `gets`, you should check if the return value is `NULL` (indicating end-of-file or an error on the standard input stream), and do something like exit the program early in that case.

Comment: @Mykkey, Given "my assignment specifies that I have to use gets()." why does code use `scanf_s()` twice?

Comment: `strcpy_s(choice, 100, "")` is utterly useless

Comment: *my assignment specifies that I have to use `gets()`*... run Mykkey, run away from this this place!

Comment: There is no such function as `gets` the C language. [Here is the C language standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2310.pdf). You can search it, there is no `gets`. You should show it to your "professor".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `gets()` is definitely a bad requirement because this function is inherently unsafe and has been removed from recent versions of the C Standard.

Yet this is what is happening:

- in the first iteration, `gets()` expected input ended with a newline, you type `triangle` and hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd>, so `choice` receives the string `"triangle"`.
- the program then request the user to enter 2 floating point numbers with `scanf_s`: for each request, the user types the number and hits the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, and `scanf_s` consumes any leading white space (including newlines) and parses the number leaving the newline in the input stream.
- for the next iteration, `gets()` reads this pending newline and returns immediately with an empty string in `choice`, which does not cause any output and the next iteration prompts again for input. This explains why you get a duplicated prompt.

To fix this problem, avoid mixing `gets` or `fgets` with `scanf_s` or `scanf()`: read the user input with `fgets()`, check for end of file and parse it with `sscanf()` one line at a time, checking for successful conversions.

Here is a modified version:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
// prevent warnings about the use of standard function sscanf
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#endif

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    const float pi = 3.1415926535;  // Constant for pi
    char line[100];
    char choice[20];
    float height, width, base, area, radius, radians, verticalHeight;

    for (;;) {
        puts("Area Calculator - Please choose one of the choices listed below\n"
             "----------------------------------------------------\n"
             "Triangle, Rectangle, Circle, Trapezium\n"
             "----------------------------------------------------");
        printf("Enter choice: ");
        if (!fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin))
            break;
        if (sscanf(line, "%19s", choice) != 1)
            continue;

        // set the command to lowercase
        for (int i = 0; choice[i]; i++) {
            choice[i] = tolower((unsigned char)choice[i]);
        }

        if (!strcmp(choice, "done")) {
            break;
        } else
        if (!strcmp(choice, "triangle")) {
            printf("Enter vertical height: ");
            if (!fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin))
                break;
            if (sscanf(line, "%f", &verticalHeight) != 1) {
                printf("input error\n");
                continue;
            }
            printf("Enter base: ");
            if (!fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin))
                break;
            if (sscanf(line, "%f", &base) != 1) {
                printf("input error\n");
                continue;
            }
            printf("Area = %.2f\n\n", 0.5 * verticalHeight * base);
        } else
        if (!strcmp(choice, "rectangle")) {
            puts("rectangle");
        } else
        if (!strcmp(choice, "circle")) {
            puts("circle");
        } else
        if (!strcmp(choice, "trapezium") || !strcmp(choice, "trapezoid")) {
            puts("trapezium");
        } else {
            printf("unsupported shape: %s\n", choice);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to fix your homework for you, but I'll drop a few hints.

1. You're using `gets()`, `scanf_s()` and so on without checking their return values. In other words, you're always assuming the "happy case". This is bad practice. You should always check and respond to those return values. For instance, if (on Linux) the user types CTRL-D (end of file) instead of typing something more meaningful and hitting ENTER, the calls will all fail from then on, and you'll be in an infinite loop. A return of EOF or 0 from `scanf_s()`, or NULL from `gets()`, should never be ignored!
2. You should always use the correct bound for a `strncpy()`/`strcpy_s()` function, rather than a literal number. So instead of a literal 100, copying the size of `choice[]` previously, you should use `sizeof(choice)`. That way, if you change the size of `choice[]`, there's no risk of causing a buffer overflow.
3. This way you're using of having `int i=1;` and later incrementing it when you're finished is baroque! Why not `#include <stdbool.h>`, have a variable called `bool done = false;` at the start, and setting `done` to `true` when you're finished, or when you get a failure return from one of the getters that indicated end of file?
4. Look at the exact semantics for `scanf_s()` with respect to line endings.  If you want a bigger hint, type "triangle", and then, for the vertical height type, "12 34" (enter). (In other words, provide two numbers, separated by a space, before you hit ENTER.) You may find this instructive.

Comment: Your remark about `gets()` is incomplete: `gets()` should never be used!

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly - however, you missed the quote, "my assignment specifies that I have to use gets()." I was addressing the assignment as described, rather than a fictional - but considerably better-specified - one.